# Sort in mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 changes order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm sending a query to an apollo server to get a list of users. I'm using mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 library (documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2)

This is my options object

```
const options = {
            page: parseInt(page),
            limit: 15,
            lean: true,
            pagination: true,
            sort:{ lastUpdate: "descending", creationDateTime:"descending"}
        }
```

Sometimes when I resend the request the result changes even though my data is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add _id to the sort for the sort to work.

Try this:

```
sort:{ _id: 1 ,lastUpdate: "descending", creationDateTime:"descending"}
```

Comment: your answer does not seem logical to me, I dont want my documents to be sorted by the id. And BTW i started an issue on github and this was marked as a bug

Comment: @asma can you post the issue id here, I also faced this and I need to follow the issue

Comment: @buddhiv here https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2/issues/18